# Moodle downgradedcore error

Tags: mysql, moodle, vps

I have a moodle installed on a VPS. MySQL server has stopped, so I have made a power cycle on my server. After restart I have got the following error on admin login:

```
ERROR!!! The code you are using is OLDER than the version that made these databases!
```

I haven't changed anything. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check version.php for the $version value and then check the mdl_config database table, search for "name = 'version'". Compare these values.

If the version in the database is definitely wrong, you *may* be able to simply reset it back down to the value in version.php (without the decimal point and numbers after it).

In general, resetting the version number this way can cause all sorts of problems, so only do this if you are really, really sure that the database has the wrong version number.

Comment: I have checked and fixed, now both: 2014111000.
It says at admin:
/mod/lesson 2014111002  2014111000
So I cannot login.

Comment: These informations are in a table and says there are newer versions available.... How can I disagree or cancel this check?

Comment: I think it is a "pluginchecknotice".

Comment: For Moodle version 2.6 and below, look in table mdl_modules for the version number for activities. For Moodle version 2.7 and above, look in mdl_config_plugins for "plugin = 'mod_lesson' AND name = 'version'"